# Upload of csv to add related products to a parent product scrambles order of skus in related_skus column

Tags: product, import, related-products, import-products

I use products that have related products (so they pull them automatically when the parent product is selected) - i need them as separate items for accounting/inventory purposes, but i sell them in bunches.

Often, one parent product will have more than one related product. The order in which they are pulled corresponds to the order they are listed in the Related section. This has an impact on my quotes/invoices because they also appear in that order. So i need them to appear in the order i want.

I use the import Add/Update function to add products when i have a lot of them to do at once - i use the related_skus column and i put them in the order i want them to appear in.

First I create all the products i need with one import, export the entire catalog, then i do a separate import just to bunch the articles together (deleting all the lines where i'm not changing anything, so only the parent products that are receiving a related product remain in the second import).

After the import, the articles in the Related section are not in the order i selected in the related_skus colmun - as i mentioned, this has an impact on my quoting/invoicing.

How can i control the import function so that articles appear in the order i want? Is it possible?